# Sails Blueprint add to Many-to-Many record

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I'm using Sails@0.10rc-7 and I'm struggling to add something to a many-to-many record.

I have multiple users and multiple groups like this:

```
// Group.js
module.exports = {

    attributes: {

        description: {
            type: 'string'
        },

        users: {
            collection: 'user',
            via: 'groups'
        }

    }

};

//User.js
module.exports = {

    attributes: {

        token: {
            type: 'string'
        },

        groups: {
            collection: 'group',
            via: 'users'
        }

    }

};
```

I have an existing group record and an existing user record. I want to connect the user to the group.

I can succesfully do a PUT request like this:

```
PUT http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/user/1
{
"groups":1
}
```

This also works:

```
PUT http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/user/1
{
"groups": [1,2]
}
```

But what if I don't know the existing groups?

Comment: I don't quite follow.  In order to add a group to a user, you would need to know the ID of the group, or else create a group inline as part of the request.  If you're looking for a way to query the groups while you create a user, like "Update user #1 with the group whose name is "Mimes", then that's just not possible with blueprints.

Comment: What about this. https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/associations.md#when-both-records-exist